# AlertDialogBox - RadioButton

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i have an AlertDialogBox and i put Radio Button on it, but i have a problem, whenever i click them they are both selected..all i want is whenever i click the one radio button it will select and when i click the another, it will unselect the other one.. how can i do that?
here are my codes..

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);



        alert.setTitle("Standard Deviation");
        alert.setIcon(R.drawable.droid);
        RadioButton one = new RadioButton(this);
        one.setText("one set");
        RadioButton two = new RadioButton(this);
        two.setText("two sets");


        LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(Treatment.this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);



        ll.addView(one);
        ll.addView(two);
        alert.setView(ll);


        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put them inside a `RadioGroup` somthing like this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Standard Deviation");
alert.setIcon(R.drawable.droid);

RadioButton one = new RadioButton(this);
one.setText("one set");
RadioButton two = new RadioButton(this);
two.setText("two sets");


RadioGroup rg=new RadioGroup(Treatment.this);
rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);


rg.addView(one);
rg.addView(two);
alert.setView(rg);


AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read [the documentation on dialogs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) before moving forward.
The examples for custom dialogs and multiple choice dialogs would be very useful in your situation. Try adding a radio group in xml with two radio buttons inside of it as the custom layout for your alert dialog.